# How to merge month and year columns in Pandas to yyyymm format?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Hello Stack overflow community!

```
Month     year    
  5       2020
  6       2020
 11       2020
```

How to merge these two columns into yearmonth (yyyymm) format in Pandas

```
yearmonth
  202005
  202006
  202011
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
df.year*100 + df.Month
Out[415]: 
0    202005
1    202006
2    202011
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

We can convert them into strings and use `zfill`:

```
yearmonth = df.year.astype(str) + df.Month.astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

Output:

```
0    202005
1    202006
2    202011
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', converters={'month': '{:0>2}'.format}).astype('str')
df['yearmonth'] = df['year'] + df['month']
print(df)
```